# Error in SQL : Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

```
select title, price, case 
    when pub_id in (
        select pub_id
        from publishers
        where state = 'ca') then price * 1.1
    when title_id in (
        select title_id
        from titleauthor
        group by title_id
        having count(au_id) > 1) then price * 1.05
    when title_id in (
        select title, sum(qty*price) NewPrice
        from titles t
        inner join sales s on t.title_id = s.title_id
        group by title
        having sum(qty*price) > 500) then Price * 1.02                  
    else price * 1.01
    end NewPrice
from titles
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the [NewPrice] column from you third `when`'s subquery.

It is ok to keep it in the `having` clause for filtering purposes, but since you are using the `in` operator, the subquery should only return the values you are trying to match `title_id` with.